# how to change the .html() from "hide" to "show"

Tags: jquery

In my code the html of the is set to "show more" on the page it self. After I click it it, it changes to "hide"
When I click it again I am trying to set it back to "show more" Not sure on how to do it after it hides from the toggle.

```
$(".show").click( function() {
    $("#men").children().toggle('slow');
    $(".show").html("hide");
});
```

Comment: can't click it after you hide it, so you need to bind show() event to something else or change the text in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `toggle` method to bind multiple click events.

```
$(".show").toggle(function() {
    $("#men").children().toggle('slow');
    $(".show").html("hide"); // this will change all `.show` elements
    // $(this).html("hide");  // this will only change the element clicked on
}, function(){
    $("#men").children().toggle('slow');
    $(".show").html("show"); // this will change all `.show` elements
    // $(this).html("hide");  // this will only change the element clicked on
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".show").click( function() {
    $("#men").children().toggle('slow');
    $(this).text(function(txt, i) {
        return txt === "hide" ? "show" : "hide";
    });
});
```